# Flutter DropDownButton with Flutter Cubit

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc, flutter-cubit

I am trying to figure out the optimal approach in creating a Flutter DropDownButton using Bloc/Cubit. I have a working solution but it is ugly.

I have a Product Page with Category DropDown button. To populate the data, I am using BlocBuilder for CategoryCubit

categoryField

```
var categoryField = Column(
      children: [
        BlocBuilder<CategoriesCubit, CategoriesState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is CategoriesLoaded) {
              if (product != null && state.selectedCategory == null) {
                BlocProvider.of<CategoriesCubit>(context)
                    .selectCategory(product!.category);
              }
              List<DropdownMenuItem<Category>> dropDownItems = state.categories
                  .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem<Category>(
                        value: e,
                        child: Text(e.categoryName),
                      ))
                  .toList();

              void onChange<Category>(cat) {
                BlocProvider.of<CategoriesCubit>(context).selectCategory(cat);
                BlocProvider.of<ProductsCubit>(context)
                    .updateProductCategory(cat);
              }

              return CustomDropdown<Category>(
                labelText: "Select Category",
                value: state.selectedCategory,
                items: dropDownItems,
                context: context,
                onChanged: onChange,
              );
            }
            return const SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
```

CategoryLoadedState

```
class CategoriesLoaded extends CategoriesState {
  final List<Category> categories;
  final List<Category>? filteredData;
  final int? sortIndex;
  final bool sortAscending;
  final Category? selectedCategory;

  CategoriesLoaded({
    required this.categories,
    this.filteredData,
    this.sortIndex,
    required this.sortAscending,
    this.selectedCategory,
  });
}
```

This field is inside a ProductPage Stateful Widget wrapped in ProductCubit and CategoryCubit. To populate the dropdown, I wrapped the widget to a BlocProvider monitoring the CategoryCubit. Also, the default value is from the CategoryLoaded state.

onChange of the dropdown value, I set the Product.category value by updating the StreamController of my ProductCubit.

This works, but what I actually want to do is just populate the dropwdown item list, then read the initial value from the ProdutCubit - Product.category rather than CategoryCubit - selectedCategory.

I also tried calling the Category API directly to get the Category List without using Bloc but I think API async call is not allowed in Stateless Widget.